# Svelte isn't updating a derived value from an input

Tags: svelte, svelte-component, svelte-store

When I load the page, `$greeting` shows with the correct value.

For some reason, it isn't updating when I change the text in the `input`.

### App.svelte

```
<script>
    import { name, greeting } from './stores.js';
</script>

<h1>{$greeting}</h1>
<input value={$name}>
```

### stores.js

```
import { writable, derived } from 'svelte/store'

export const name = writable('world')

export const greeting = derived(
    name,
    $name => `Hello ${$name}!`
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to `bind:value` on the `input` like so:

```
<input bind:value={$name}>
```

The way you had it would only work on page load. After that, it wasn't listening to changes on `input` and that's why `$name` wasn't updating.

`bind:value` is similar to doing `onchange` in HTML:

```
<input
    onchange="event => name.set(event.target.value)"
    value={$name}
>
```